# Selecting or passing Firestore items to a new page (route)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of documents from my Firestore where I can check and uncheck the trailing checkboxes just fine. I also have a bottomnav bar with a button to include any of the "checked" items to a new page or maybe favorites section.
I am having trouble coming up with a way to push and navigate the selected items. See link below - thx

[Example - Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSzId.png)

```
class _SelectScreenState extends State<SelectScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Select Exercises')),
      body: _buildBody(context),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        elevation: 4.0,
        icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
        label: const Text('Add to workout'),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {},
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('exercises').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();

        return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    return ListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      children: snapshot.map((data) => _buildListItem(context, data)).toList(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot data) {
    final record = Record.fromSnapshot(data);


    return Padding(
      key: ValueKey(record.name),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        ),
        child: Exercise(
          title: record.name,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Exercise extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  Exercise({this.title});

  @override
  _ExerciseState createState() => _ExerciseState();
}

class _ExerciseState extends State<Exercise> {
  bool selected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(widget.title),
      trailing: Checkbox(
          value: selected,
          onChanged: (bool val) {
            setState(() {
              selected = val;
            });
          }),
    );
  }
}

class Record {
  final String name;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  Record.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : assert(map['name'] != null),
        name = map['name'];

  Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);

  @override
  String toString() => "Record<$name:>";
}
```

Comment: i think you should create a temporal list with the selected item and send it by constructor to the screen you want to navigate (or whatever state management are you using).

Comment: I am trying to get a similar outcome like this - https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2/#3 - but with checkboxes.

Comment: or do you have a brief example of the temporal list? - thanks for your input

Comment: they have it in ther this line `final Set<WordPair> _saved = Set<WordPair>();` they use a Set thats because they dont want items to repeat (if you will allow that use a list) so in the method you do the selection add saved.add(item) for adding it. and then you could send it the whole Set (or List) so you will be able to know with items were selected.